# Jetpack Compose: Content color of TabRow

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In my app, I am using `TabRow`, that has two tabs:

[image]

I do set the content color with

```
TabRow(
  ...
  contentColor = Color.Black,
  ...
)
```

While "ACTIVE" is really displayed in black, I also want "INACTIVE" in black and not grey, but in a different font weight.

I don't see any chance to directly do this with `TabRow`.

Is there any other way to do this right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this using the `Tab` component itself.

```
val isSelected = pagerState.currentPage == index
Tab(
    text = {
        Text(
            "Tab $title",
            fontWeight = if (isSelected) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Light,
            color = Color.Black
        )
    },
    selected = isSelected,
    onClick = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Totally overlooked the Tab itself.